# Strange output of C++ Vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I just started to code using [Vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and wrote the following basic code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> second(4,100);

    cout<<second[0]<<endl; 
    cout<<second[1]<<endl; 
    cout<<second[2]<<endl; 
    cout<<second[3]<<endl; 
    cout<<second[4]<<endl; 
    cout<<second[5]<<endl; 
    cout<<second[6]<<endl; 
    cout<<second[7]<<endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is the following

```
100
100
100
100
0
135145
0
0

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 10ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Why is the output of `cout<<second[5]` different from the rest of the indices greater than 3. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your vector has size 4. So any access with index higher than 3 is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
vector<int> second(4,100);
```

The first argument tells the constructor the size of the vector, the second one the value it should use to fill it with.

You've created a vector of size 4 and that means that the last valid element is `second[3]`. Anything beyond that writes or reads out of bounds to/from memory that doesn't belong to the vector and invokes undefined behaviour.

You can use `push_back` method to safely append elements at the end.

Comment: So the fact that apart from 5, the values for other indices above 3 is  0 is just a matter of coincidence?

Comment: Any index outside the range `[0,4)` is undefined behavior.  It might read out of bounds, but most implementations will simply crash, at least in debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

You create a vector with 4 elements, which are initialized with 100.
At that point:

```
cout<<second[4]<<endl;
```

you run out of bounds and it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The [`std::vector`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) your are using accepts two arguments — count and value. In your case, you are creating a vector of 4 elements. However, you are trying to access 8 elements. This triggers [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

One interesting fact is while `operator[](size_type)` does not check the valid range allowing you to trigger UB, [`std::vector::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) method does, and will throw an exception if the index is out of range.

Comment: `operator[]( size_type )` may check the range.  Most do, at least in debug mode, and will crash the application.  Which is generally preferred to an exception.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I think most don't check in release. I never heard of any runtime doing that (thought I use mostly GNU)

Comment: Most don't check in release, but g++ checks if you use the options `-D_GLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC` (which should be the case in debug).  Regretfully, it's an all or nothing thing; the options change the size of `std::vector`.  So you can't just turn the checking off where the profiler says you must.

Answer (score 0):

You are only initialising the first four elements in the vector, the rest are random uninitialized memory.

Comment: actually, the rest could be anything - some other part of your program's memory or no valid memory location at all - it's undefined.